# Schedule Wordpress custom post status changes at specific times

Tags: wordpress, function

I'd like to put a function or action in our functions.php that automatically publishes ONE specific post at a specific time, then returns it to draft status after a few hours. This would be reoccuring for that specific post. EX:

Monday-Friday
3pm: published --- 10pm: draft

Saturday/Sunday
3pm: published --- 830pm: draft

I've been looking at WP-Cron, and Post Status Transition, but haven't quite figured out making them work together. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd duly appreciate it. THANKS!

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/schedule-your-posts-in-wordpress/     please check this

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to get one specific post to be published, then returned to draft on a reoccurring basis during the week. The regular WP scheduler doesn't really help with that.

Comment: To be clear you want to set the time on a specific post and when time comes it will automatically published and if time up the post status will changed automatically draft?

Comment: Yes. On one specific post on a regular basis. Does it seem doable? Thanks a lot...